# iTextPdf: Extract text from PrintJob

Tags: android, printing, io, itext

I working on project for thermal printer where I using [Android Print Service](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrintService) to print bill from third party application. Because I have to print as raw text, so I need extract it from [PrintJob](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/printservice/PrintJob) using [iTextPdf](https://itextpdf.com/en/resources/installation-guides/installing-itext-g-android).

Everything was alright until now, when I saw errors (**stacktrace bellow**) in Crashlytics on some devices. They have a problem once per ~15 print sessions. Not even sure how I can replicate this error or why occur not every time.

```
Caused by java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.read + 435(IoBridge.java:435)
       at java.io.FileInputStream.read + 179(FileInputStream.java:179)
       at java.io.InputStream.read + 162(InputStream.java:162)
       at com.itextpdf.text.io.StreamUtil.inputStreamToArray(StreamUtil.java)
       at com.itextpdf.text.io.RandomAccessSourceFactory.createSource(RandomAccessSourceFactory.java)
       at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.(Unknown Source)
       at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.(Unknown Source)
       at sk.blockomat.vrp.pdf.PdfHelper$Companion.extractText(PdfHelper.java)
       at sk.blockomat.vrp.services.CustomPrinterService.extractPrintJobText(CustomPrinterService.java)
       at sk.blockomat.vrp.services.CustomPrinterService.onPrintJobQueued(CustomPrinterService.java)
       at android.printservice.PrintService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage + 516(PrintService.java:516)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage + 102(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop + 136(Looper.java:136)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main + 5584(ActivityThread.java:5584)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Method.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke + 515(Method.java:515)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run + 1268(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main + 1084(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
       at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(NativeStart.java)
```

This is code what I use for text extraction for PrintJob:

```
override fun onPrintJobQueued(job: PrintJob) {
    //mark job as started
    job.start()

    //transform print job to text
    var text = extractPrintJobText(job)

    //print text
    ...
}

private fun extractPrintJobText(job: PrintJob): String {
    val descriptor = job.document.data!!.fileDescriptor

    //this stream look some way corrupted
    val stream = FileInputStream(descriptor)

    if(!stream.fd.valid()) {
        //I never saw this warning, so I expect every stream is valid
        logger.logWarning(TAG, "Stream fd is not valid!")
    }

    return extractText(stream)
}
```

This is part of application where I get error.

```
fun extractText(stream: InputStream): String {
    //line where I somethimes get EBADF (bad file number) error
    val pdfReader = PdfReader(stream)

    return extractText(pdfReader)
}

private fun extractText(pdfReader: PdfReader): String {
    val pages = pdfReader.numberOfPages
    var parsedText = ""

    try {
        for (i in 0 until pages) {
            //Extracting the content from the different pages
            parsedText += PdfTextExtractor.getTextFromPage(pdfReader, i + 1).trim() + "\n"
        }

        return parsedText
    } finally {
        pdfReader.close()
    }
}
```

Comment: Currently, you check if the stream is valid by calling `if(!stream.fd.valid())` inside `extractPrintJobText`. Then you show a log if it is not and call `return extractText(stream)`. The problem is that if the stream is not valid, you still call `extractText`. For some reason `FileInputStream` is not valid, my guess is that an invalid File was passed or the inputstream is closed. If the `FileInputStream` is not valid you should not call `extractPrintJobText`, you should let the user know the file is invalid, or figure out why it is invalid.

Comment: @HB. Agree, there should be throw error or something and I'll fix that. Right now it was only sent to Crashlytics. But it not occur not even once in log for error cases. So it look like stream.fd is always valid.

Comment: Swapped iTextPdf for PdfBox and still getting same error. So now I know, something is wrong with getting input stream from print job.